# Gradient descent with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm trying to make a gradient descent algorithm where the parameters need to be constrained by a set of linear equations. So if $\theta_i$ are parameters and I'm trying to minimize $E$, then
$$
\theta_i \rightarrow \theta_i - \alpha \nabla_{\theta_i} E 
$$
except that $\theta_i$ must also obey more than one linear equations of the form
$$
\sum_i \theta_i c_i = Z 
$$

I don't want to add a penalty function to $E$ because I want this to be an exact constraint. I'm wondering if anyone can point me to a method that could do this.

I'll briefly describe a vague idea I have, which is to leave $\theta_i$ unconstrained and then transform them to $\tilde{\theta_i}$, which would follow the constraints and be input to $E$. So
$$
\theta_i \rightarrow \theta_i - \alpha \nabla_{\theta_i} E(\tilde{\theta_i}) 
$$
$$
\sum_i \tilde{\theta_i} c_i = Z 
$$

My idea for the transformation would be to remove the component of $\theta_i$ spanned by the vectors $c_i$ in the constraint equations, then solve the linear constraint equations in this space, and add the solution back to $\theta_i$, making $\theta_i$ free to move in the space not spanned by the constraint vectors. However I can't think of a straight forward way to do this.

Comment: See [Gradient descent with constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54855) and [What is the difference between projected gradient descent and ordinary gradient descent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/571068).

Comment: Parameterize the solution space, rewrite the cost function in terms of the parameters and then do gradient descent on the parameters.